# Feature file not linked to stepdefs

Tags: cucumber

I have written a feature file, Stepdefs and TestRunner class .
After running TestRunner class by Run with Junit configuration , i am getting the proper output. But i cant see the my Steps in feature files are related to StepsDefs.

Any suggestions, tried few workarounds given in stackoverflow, didnot work for me.

Here is my Maven Project

[Maven Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQNXr.png)

```
My POM.xml

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>BDDFrameWork</groupId>
  <artifactId>BDDFrameWork</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Engine1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <profiles>
  <profile>
  <id>Regression</id>
    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
             <source>1.6</source>
             <target>1.6</target>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  </profile>
  
  <profile>
  <id>Smoke</id>
    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
             <source>1.6</source>
             <target>1.6</target>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  </profile>
  </profiles>

  <dependencies>
  
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.1</version>
</dependency>
   
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.cobertura/cobertura -->
<!--dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>-->
 
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.1</version>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>14.1.0</version>
</dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>  
 
  

    
    


    
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
  </dependency>
  

  
    
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

- Can any one suggest me how can i see the steps in feature files linked to its corresponding stepdefs

Regards,
Harmohan Singh

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Natural plugin and Cucumber Eclipse plugin both , then i installed Cucumber Eclipse plugin again,restarted by eclipse. Now i can see my steps in Features files linked to corresponding stepdefs.

Regards,
Harmohan

Answer (score 0):

Most of the error appears because of misconfiguration and not downloaded jar files via dependencies (We can make force downloded via maven cycle)